# One web page with multiple URL's using PHP

Tags: php, web, include

I was wondering how you could make it so that "website.com" has an index.php file that simply opens "website.com/home" but without changing the URL. I originally had it so that it used a PHP include of "website.com/home/index.php" inside "website.com/index.php" but when i had to use includes inside of "website.com/home/index.php" it stopped working as it was running the includes from "website.com/index.php" instead of "website.com/home/index.php" is there any way to simply send the file "website.com/home/index.php" and have it run from "website.com/home/index.php" without changing the URL? I would want to avoid having to use the absolute location to simplify it and so i can copy and paste the code into other directories without having to edit it accordingly.

Comment: Check out Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chdir()` to navigate to the correct folder, then `include("index.php");`